# Floating action button label on right side

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am using [wangjiegulu/RapidFloatingActionButton](https://github.com/wangjiegulu/RapidFloatingActionButton)

Here my menu shows like below:[image: Floating_menu]

But I want to show my labels in right side, I tried in different way but no luck,
please help me.

please find my attached xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_home"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/windowBackground"
tools:context="com.wsolus.chathuranga.simplifya.Home">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:clickable="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/supermainlayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/windowBackground"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lnname2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lnname4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/windowBackground"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvname"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:text="Appointment List"
                            android:textColor="@color/apptlistdark"
                            android:textSize="23sp" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.97"
                        android:background="@color/windowBackground"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinnercmp"
                            android:layout_width="290dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="end"
                            android:background="@drawable/spinnerstyl" />


                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2px"
                    android:background="@color/listviewbackground" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lnlayoutlist"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lnname4"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layouttext"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/lvappointments"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="2.89"
                            android:divider="@color/listviewbackground"
                            android:dividerHeight="2dp"
                            android:paddingRight="3dp"
                            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />


                    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lnlayoutnoapp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lnname4"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/lvnoapp"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:divider="@color/listviewbackground"
                            android:dividerHeight="2dp"
                            android:paddingRight="3dp"
                            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />

                    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/flag"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="280dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/img" />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lnrl1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
                    android:alpha=".8"
                    android:background="#4266A1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvdate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvcmp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="17dp" />


                </LinearLayout>


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@color/listviewbackground">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btndownload"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.5"
                            android:text="Left Button"
                            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:visibility="gone" />


                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.5"
                            android:text="Right Button"
                            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </RelativeLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lnraddr"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/flag"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/windowBackground"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvaddr1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/appgry"
                            android:textSize="15dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvaddr2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/appgry"
                            android:textSize="15dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvfulcty"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/appgry"
                            android:textSize="15dp" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="2px"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/listviewbackground" />


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/img_loc"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.50"
                        android:background="@color/windowBackground"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <!--<ImageView-->
                        <!--android:layout_width="32dp"-->
                        <!--android:layout_height="39dp"-->
                        <!--android:src="@drawable/ic_newloc" />-->

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2px"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lnraddr"
                    android:background="@color/listviewbackground" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvdetail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lnraddr"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/appgry"
                    android:textSize="17dp" />


            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <com.wangjie.rapidfloatingactionbutton.RapidFloatingActionLayout xmlns:rfal="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_rfal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        rfal:rfal_frame_alpha="0.7"
        rfal:rfal_frame_color="#ffffff">

        <com.wangjie.rapidfloatingactionbutton.RapidFloatingActionButton xmlns:rfab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_rfab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            rfab:rfab_color_normal="@color/btnPending"
            rfab:rfab_color_pressed="@color/catgListHigligt"
            rfab:rfab_drawable="@drawable/rfab__drawable_rfab_default"
            rfab:rfab_shadow_color="#999999"
            rfab:rfab_shadow_dx="0dp"
            rfab:rfab_shadow_dy="5dp"
            rfab:rfab_shadow_radius="7dp"
            rfab:rfab_size="normal" />
    </com.wangjie.rapidfloatingactionbutton.RapidFloatingActionLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Share your xml..

Comment: @ Akshay please check my above question

Answer (score 1):

Use this [Library](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton)

in gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
```

}

in xml:

```
 <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
        fab:menu_showShadow="true"
        fab:menu_shadowColor="#66000000"
        fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
        fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
        fab:menu_shadowYOffset="3dp"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="#DA4336"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="#E75043"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="50"
        fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
        fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
        fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
        fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
        fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingTop="4dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingRight="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingBottom="4dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingLeft="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_textColor="#FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_labels_textSize="14sp"
        fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
        fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333333"
        fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444444"
        fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
        fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
        fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
        fab:menu_labels_style="@style/YourCustomLabelsStyle"
        fab:menu_labels_position="left"
        fab:menu_openDirection="up"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        fab:menu_fab_label="your_label_here"
        fab:menu_fab_show_animation="@anim/my_show_animation"
        fab:menu_fab_hide_animation="@anim/my_hide_animation">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/menu_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_star"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="Menu item 1" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
```

here :

```
fab:menu_labels_position="left"   //change it to see labels at right
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but it gives me some errors "ClassNotfound" Exceptions

Comment: follow the library page to set up ...properly

Comment: "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FloatingActionButton_fab_colorNormal"  I got this error

Comment: you need to add this: `xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`...in root layout

Comment: I already added this to my root  "xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: add this in gradle: `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'`

Comment: my  compileSdkVersion 24 I already added compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144421/discussion-between-john-morgan-and-rafsanahmad007).

Answer (score 1):

In the FloatingActionsMenu add the property fab_labelsPosition to right

```
<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu

        app:fab_labelsPosition="right">
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it in **RapidActionfloatingButton** but you can achieve the same by using this code inside **RelativeLayout**.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ... />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="#FF00FF00"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="textview2" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Just tweak the alignments as per your need. But, this should also do the job.